# Grails Criteria distinct doesn't work

Tags: grails, criteria, nhibernate-projections

In my app I use createCriteria for getting a list according some criteria.
roleMapping contains user.

I use the following code:

```
def getTeamOfCompany(def company,def offset=0){
        def c = roleMapping.createCriteria()
        def result = c.list{
            eq('company',company)
            eq('isCurrentCompany',true)
            firstResult offset
            maxResults 10
            distinct('user')
            user{
                order "lastname", "asc"
            }
        }
    return result
}
```

I use the distinct in order to not get the same user twice, but it didn't work.

If I put projections on the distinct I'll get a list of users instead roleMapping

Comment: Can you try `result.unique{ it.user }` on previous code which was giving you roleMapping collection. Projections actually select columns for you

Comment: what do you exactly want? do you want one role per one user? why?

Comment: result.unique{ it.user } is a neat trick to solve the problem, but breaks the proper pagination behavior of the criteria query.